# Grouping and flattening list with linq and lambda

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, grouping

I have the following class

```
public class SolicitacaoConhecimentoTransporte
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public string CodigoOriginal { get; set; }

    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public List<CaixaConhecimentoTransporte> Caixas { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way of achiveing the same behavior of the code below using Linq (with lambda expression syntax),

```
List<SolicitacaoConhecimentoTransporte> auxList = new List<SolicitacaoConhecimentoTransporte>();

foreach (SolicitacaoConhecimentoTransporte s in listaSolicitacao)
{
    SolicitacaoConhecimentoTransporte existing =
                    auxList.FirstOrDefault(f => f.CodigoOriginal == s.CodigoOriginal &&
                                                f.Data == s.Data && 
                                                f.ID == s.ID);

    if (existing == null)
    {
        auxList.Add(s);
    }
    else
    {
        existing.Caixas.AddRange(s.Caixas);
    }
}

return auxList;
```

In other words, group all entities that have equal properties and flat all lists into one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're mutating `existing` by calling(`existing.Caixas.AddRange(s.Caixas);`), doing this in linq is a bad idea. If you create new object instead of using existing that's fine.

Comment: Can you clarify why is it a bad idea?

Comment: Your code isn't bad. Doing the same in linq is bad as you need to mutate it. LINQ-Q stands for query, linq is for querying data, not modifying them. If you see Sergey Berezovskiy's answer which is good, he's not violating this. He didn't mutate anything. Did you see my point?

Comment: I understand you. I don´t know how does SelectMany work internally, but, as you said, his LINQ does not seem to modify the collection, so everything is fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use anonymous object to group by three properties. Then project each group to new `SolicitacaoConhecimentoTransporte` instance. Use `Enumerable.SelectMany` to get flattened sequence of `CaixaConhecimentoTransporte` from each group:

```
listaSolicitacao.GroupBy(s => new { s.CodigoOriginal, s.Data, s.ID })
   .Select(g => new SolicitacaoConhecimentoTransporte {
         ID = g.Key.ID,
         Data = g.Key.Data,
         CodigoOriginal = g.Key.CodigoOriginal,
         Caixas = g.SelectMany(s => s.Caixas).ToList()
    }).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I knew about the SelectMany Method to flat the list, I didn´t realize the "trick" with the anonymous for grouping.